# Advanced broadcasting in TensorFlow (or Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, array-broadcasting

In TensorFlow I have a rank-2 tensor `M` (a matrix) of shape `[D, D]` and a rank-3 tensor `T` of shape `[D, D, D]`.

I need to combine them to form a new matrix `R` as follows: the element `R[a, b+c-a]` is given by the sum of all the elements `T[a, b, c]*M[b, c]` where `b+c-a` is constant (where `b+c-a` has to be between 0 and `D-1`).

An inefficient way to create `R` is with nested `for` loops over the indices and a check that `b+c-a` does not exceed `D-1` (e.g. in numpy):

```
R = np.zeros([D,D])

for a in range(D):
  for b in range(D):
    for c in range(D):
      if 0 <= b+c-a < D:
        R[a, b+c-a] += T[a, b, c]*M[b, c]
```

but I would like to use broadcasting and/or other more efficient methods.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show the `for` loop code, it's not possible to understand what you want from this explanation.

Comment: But `b + c - a` may take the same value for more than one combination of `a`, `b` and `c`, even if `a` is fixed (e.g. for `(a=2, b=1, c=3)` and `(a=2, b=3, c=1)` the result is 2). Which of the values should `R[a, b + c - a]` take? Or should it be a combination (addition, product)?

Comment: @jedhesa I corrected that part, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize that calculation as follows:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
D = 10
M = np.random.rand(D, D)
T = np.random.rand(D, D, D)
# Original calculation
R = np.zeros([D, D])
for a in range(D):
    for b in range(D):
        for c in range(D):
            if 0 <= b + c - a < D:
                R[a, b + c - a] += T[a, b, c] * M[b, c]
# Vectorized calculation
tm = T * M
a = np.arange(D)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
b, c = np.ogrid[:D, :D]
col_idx = b + c - a
m = (col_idx >= 0) & (col_idx < D)
row_idx = np.tile(a, [1, D, D])
R2 = np.zeros([D, D])
np.add.at(R2, (row_idx[m], col_idx[m]), tm[m])
# Check result
print(np.allclose(R, R2))
# True
```

Alternatively, you could consider using Numba to accelerate the loops:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def calculation_nb(T, M, D):
    tm = T * M
    R = np.zeros((D, D), dtype=tm.dtype)
    for a in nb.prange(D):
      for b in range(D):
        for c in range(max(a - b, 0), min(D + a - b, D)):
          R[a, b + c - a] += tm[a, b, c]
    return R

print(np.allclose(R, calculation_nb(T, M, D)))
# True
```

In a couple of quick tests, even without parallelization, this is quite faster than NumPy.